# Connected to wifi but the pages are just loading (internet is not working) on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

### About

iPhone 6

12.4.4

### Issue

It is possible for me to connect to the wifi through setting >> wifi. After connecting, I tried using safari. The page is loading and loading and loading..... (never-ending). And for WhatsApp, they just show connecting...

I tried resetting the network settings and it didn't help. What can I do to fix this issue? Does this seem like a hardware issue or software?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the content blockers?

Comment: Do you need to log into a network ? http://captive.apple.com. very well could be router configuration https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238307/iphone-is-supposedly-connected-to-wifi-but-has-no-connection-to-neither-internet?rq=1